# How should display the textfield in the specific position inside the form of j2me?

Tags: java-me

how?
Display the TextField in the form in the custom position (that is the position is dynamic).That is displaying the text field in a specific point,co-ordinates,position,etc in the form using j2me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

default j2me standard will not allow you to do that

but you can doit with different frameworks available in j2me

you can use **j2me polish, lwuit or twuik.**

Comment: Mihir thanks for ur answer.But i need another help.I heard from many of J2ME developers that don't use J2ME Polish.But did not know anything about lwuit and twuik.Send me some details about there installations how should i integerate them with my project in sun wirless toolkit,Functionality,etc.